# Need help installing clamav from Source

Tags: linux

I am trying to install ClamAV from source code but I run into problem when I run **make** command. Here is what I get:

```
/bin/sed: can't read files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1/libclamav/libclamunrar.la: No such file or directory
libtool: link: `files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1/libclamav/libclamunrar.la' is not a valid libtool archive
make[4]: *** [libclamunrar_iface.la] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/User/Temporary files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1/libclamav'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/User/Temporary files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1/libclamav'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/User/Temporary files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1/libclamav'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/User/Temporary files/clamav/clamav-0.98.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Please use the Answer box below to post this; that way, it shows that someone has figured out the answer to this question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. The problem is that the direcory where I unpacked source code has space in it /Temporary files/ So the conclusion is avoid alway spaces in directory when possible